# BroadcastReceiver is not working

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have implemented this broadcast reciever:

```
public class ServiceManager extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private final String BOOT_ACTION = "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED";
    private final String BOOT_ACTION_FIRST_LAUNCH = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH";
    private final String BOOT_ACTION_RESTARTED = "android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // All registered broadcasts are received by this
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (action.equalsIgnoreCase(BOOT_ACTION) || action.equalsIgnoreCase(BOOT_ACTION_FIRST_LAUNCH) || 
                action.equalsIgnoreCase(BOOT_ACTION_RESTARTED)) {
             // TODO: Action
        } 
    }

}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<receiver android:name="package.service.ServiceManager" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH" />
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.PACKAGE_RESTARTED" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

The BOOT_COMPLETED action is working right, but, the PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH and PACKAGE_RESTARTED are not working. I need to launch my broadcast receiver when I launch my app, that's why I'm using these actions. But, when I launch or restart the app, the receiver is not working. It only works when I restart my mobile phone. Are there something wrong in my source?

Comment: Just in general: Using string constants is a good thing to do. In case of intent action strings, you don't have to do that on your own though. All of these strings have their own constant within the android framework, most belong to the Intent class. E.g. see [`Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED). Rather use these, avoids confusion due to the occasional typo when defining them yourself. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically it seems that `PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH` will be broadcasted once your app is run for the first time after boot/reboot. And `PACKAGE_RESTARTED` should be broadcasted if your application activity stack is removed and then your app is clicked to start again (like restart).

However, you may simply achieve this by broadcasting a custom action string when ever your app is launched (perhaps from your first activity).

Answer (score 6):

FYI: `PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH` is **only** sent to the installer package, i.e. whatever you used to install the application - for most end users that would be Android Market.

**Edit:**
Oh, and for "PACKAGE_RESTARTED", break that one out into its own `<intent-filter>` and add a

```
<data android:scheme="package"/>
```

since that one comes with an URI and an explicit scheme.

Answer (score 0):

Manifest:

```
...
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></>
...
<receiver android:name=".AutoStart">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"></action>
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
...
```

Receiver:

```
package YourPackage;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;

public class AutoStart extends BroadcastReceiver
{   
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
    {   
        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"))
        {
            // Your code
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The intent `android.intent.action.PACKAGE_FIRST_LAUNCH` is introduced in Android API Level 12. If you are using lesser API Level it will not work. So change your project settings accordingly.